# Symfony impersonation switch event

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Ill try to keep it short.
I've activated Symfony 2.8's SwitchUser functionality, and hooked in a working SwitchUserListener as a service, as per the Symfony Cookbook. Now, when i try to access the user like this data in the event like this:

```
class SwitchUserListener
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em_item)
    {
        $this->em = $em_item;
    }

    public function onSwitchUser(SwitchUserEvent $event)
    {
        $log_content =  "switching user: " + $event->getRequest->getUser()->getUsername();
        $log = new Log();
        $log->setLogContent($log_content);
        $this->em->persist($log);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

I get an exception that i cannot call `getUsername` on undefined, from which i conclude that getUser doesn't return anything. Does anybody know why that is? 
I want to log something to the database that tells me, whenever someone impersonates another user, which user impersonates which other user.
Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply forgot the parenthesis in this line:

```
$log_content =  "switching user: " + $event->getRequest->getUser()->getUsername();
```

Try this instead:

```
$log_content =  "switching user: " + $event->getRequest()->getUser()->getUsername();
```

If what you want is to log the user you'd be switching to, maybe you should be using the `getTargetUser` method instead:

```
$log_content =  "switching user: " + $event->getTargetUser()->getUsername();
```

Comment: doesn't seem to change anything. apparently `$event->getRequest()->getUser()` simply returns nothing...

Comment: Well, i want both :) already figured the target user out, but i need some way to get *who* is trying to impersonate that user.

Comment: The problem is that the event is raised `after` the impersonation takes place. So I'm afraid that this would not be the right place to get the previous user.

Comment: Is there any way at all to determine if someone quits the impersonation?